# Activity пересоздается после смены Activity

Tags: java, android

У меня есть 3 `Activity`. 1 - `MainActivity`, 2 - `InfoActivity`, 3 - `ChangelogActivity`.
Если я нахожусь на 2 Activity и перехожу на 3, а затем обратно , то все нормально, но если со 2 перехожу на 1 и обратно , то 2 активити пересоздается и данные на нем теряются. В частности ProgreasBar обнуляется.

Немного кода который может быть полезен.

- AndroidManifest.xml

  ```
  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <application
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:supportsRtl="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|uiMode">
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity
          android:name=".FirmwareInfo"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|uiMode"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
      <activity
          android:name=".FirmwareChangelog"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|uiMode"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
      <activity
          android:name=".SettingsActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden|uiMode"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
  </application>
  ```
- MainActivity Overrided Methods

  ```
      //Действия во время созданиея MainActivity
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

          //Конструктор Override
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          //Проверка прав
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSION_STRING_ARRAY, REQUEST_PERMISSION_PHONE_STATE);

          //Инициализация
          utils = new FFUtils();
          gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.firmware_grid_view);

          //Установка модели в тайтл
          if(deviceModel != null)
              setTitle(deviceModel);
          else
              setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));


          ///////////////////////////////////////
          //       Advanced listener блок
          ///////////////////////////////////////

          //Клик по элементу GridView
          gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
              {
                  try
                  {
                      System.out.println(lastFirmwares.get(position));
                      String[] lastFirmwareArray = lastFirmwares.get(position).split("\\|");
                      Intent intent = new Intent(getThis(), FirmwareInfo.class);

                      intent.putExtra("firmwareName",lastFirmwareArray[0]).
                              putExtra("firmwareType",lastFirmwareArray[1]).
                              putExtra("firmwareLink",lastFirmwareArray[2]).
                              putExtra("firmwareSize",lastFirmwareArray[3]).
                              putExtra("firmwareLastmod",lastFirmwareArray[4]).
                              putExtra("firmwareCount",lastFirmwares.size()).
                              putExtra("firmwareId",position);

                      startActivity(intent);
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      Log.e("GetFirmwarePosition",ex.getMessage());
                  }

              }
          });
      }

      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      }

      @Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      }




      //Действия после загрузки формы
      @Override
      protected void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
          getDelegate().onStart();

          //Получаем список моделей
          modelsList = utils.getModelsList(MODELSLIST_LINK);
          //Получаем приведенную к общему виду модель
          if(modelManuallyChanged == false)
              deviceModel = utils.getDeviceModel(modelsList,utils.getDeviceFullModel());
          //Добавляем модель в тайтл
          setTitle(deviceModel);
      }

      //Подключаем меню
      @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
          getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
          return true;
      }
  ```
- InfoActivity Overrided Methods

  ```
      //Действия во время созданиея FirmwareInfo
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_firmware_info);

          this.setTitle("FirmwareInfo");

          //Инициализация
          utils = new FFUtils();
          firmware_info_lastmod_textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firmware_info_lastmod_textview);
          firmware_info_size_textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firmware_info_size_textview);
          firmware_info_download_progressbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.firmware_info_download_progressbar);
          //firmware_info_download_progressbar.setProgress(0);


          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
              int progress = savedInstanceState.getInt("progress");
              firmware_info_download_progressbar.setProgress(progress);
          }



          //Убираем тень
          getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

      }

      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      }

      @Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          savedInstanceState.putInt("progressbar_progress", firmware_info_download_progressbar.getProgress());
      }

      @Override
      public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          int progressbar_progress = savedInstanceState.getInt("progressbar_progress");
          firmware_info_download_progressbar.setProgress(progressbar_progress);
      }


      //Действия после загрузки формы
      @Override
      protected void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
          getDelegate().onStart();


          firmwareName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareName");
          firmwareType = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareType");
          firmwareLink = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareLink");
          firmwareSize = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareSize");
          firmwareLastmod = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareLastmod");
          firmwareId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("firmwareId");
          firmwareCount = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("firmwareCount");


          if(firmwareName != null)
          {
              setTitle(firmwareName + " " + firmwareType);
              firmware_info_lastmod_textview.setText(getString(R.string.last_mod) + " " + firmwareLastmod);
              firmware_info_size_textview.setText(getString(R.string.size) + " " + utils.convertToMegabyte(firmwareSize));
          }
      }
  ```
- Changelog Overrided Methods

  ```
      //Действия во время созданиея FirmwareChangelog
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_firmware_changelog);

          //Инициализация
          utils = new FFUtils();
          firmware_changelog_view_model = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firmware_changelog_view_model);
          firmware_changelog_view_changelog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firmware_changelog_view_changelog);
          firmware_changelog_view_changelog.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

          //Убираем тень
          getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

          //Убираем Titile
          getSupportActionBar().hide();
      }

      @Override
      public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
          super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      }
      @Override
      public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
          super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
          outState.putBundle("newBundy", newBundy);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
          savedInstanceState.getBundle("newBundy");
      }

      //Действия после загрузки формы
      @Override
      protected void onStart() {
          super.onStart();
          getDelegate().onStart();

          firmwareName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareName");
          firmwareType = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareType");
          firmwareLink = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareLink");
          firmwareSize = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareSize");
          firmwareLastmod = getIntent().getExtras().getString("firmwareLastmod");

          firmware_changelog_view_model.setText(firmwareName);

          Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  try
                  {
                      //Получаем List со всеми строками feature из changelog
                      parsedChangelog = parseXmlString(prepareXpp(utils.getXmlFromUrl(firmwareLink.replace("update.zip","changelog.xml"))));
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      Log.e("Parse error",ex.getMessage());
                  }

                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  for (String s : parsedChangelog)
                  {
                      sb.append(s);
                      sb.append("\t");
                  }
                  utils.universalSetText(firmware_changelog_view_changelog,sb.toString());
                  //firmware_changelog_view_changelog.setText(sb.toString());
              }
          });
          t.start();
      }
  ```

Comment: извините за код , писал данный пост с телефона , буду у компьютера , исправлю

Comment: Попроуйте возвращаться на предыдущую активити не через onBackPressed или finish а через запуск Intent - так активити не должна помереть  и данные теряться не должны

Comment: т.е. мне нужно в активити 2 подменить нажатие кнопки назад , добавив туда intent на активити 1 ?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и как это сделать ? через override onBackPressed?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил код
 public void onBackPressed()
 {
      Intent intent = new Intent(getThis(),MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
после этого и MainActivity обнуляется

Comment: после добавления onActivityResult, на MainActivity для получения значения progress с InfoActivity, прогресс бар теперь имеет последнее значение, но все равно меня это не устраивает, дело в том что прогресс бар обновляется за счет обновления данных из потока(загрузки данных), в этот поток на запуске передается линк на ProgressBar с InfoActivity и после перехода с InfoActivity на MainActivity линк на ProgressBar перестает быть актуальным, так как InfoActivity пересоздается

Answer (score 0):

Для практически полного решения данной проблемы я создал IntentService ,который и занимается загрузкой , так же во время изменения количества загруженных данных в процентном соотношении данные отправляются в BroadcastReciever который находится на InfoActivity , теперь данные прогресс бара обновляются, но есть все же остаётся проблема , она заключается в том что после перехода с MainActivity на InfoActivity значение ProgreasBar равно 0 , длюо того момента пока сервис не отправит данные на в BroadcastReciever, так вот , вопрос такой , могу ли я как то преждевременно запросить данные у сервиса ?

Comment: Да, вы можете, например, писать всё время данные в SharedPreferences или вообще в БД и при первом запуске активити оттуда данные брать. Ещё должно через Binder подключиться к сервису и напрямую взять его переменную. И ещё несколько способов разного уровня сложности, красоты и требуемых библиотек